# Checking a type and casting to a concrete type for function signature

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I have the following code and feel like I can improve it.  Specifically I'd like to get rid of the switch and force casting.  Polygon has the following type signature:

`let polygon: MKShape & MKGeoJSONObject`

```swift
switch polygon {
case is MKMultiPolygon:
    let multiPoly = polygon as! MKMultiPolygon
    renderer = MKMultiPolygonRenderer(multiPolygon: multiPoly)
case is MKPolygon:
    let polygon = polygon as! MKPolygon
    renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: polygon)
default:
    fatalError("Should have had a renderer")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep the switch approach and use `case let` to cast your object to the appropriate type:

```
switch polygon {
case let object as MKMultiPolygon:
    renderer = MKMultiPolygonRenderer(multiPolygon: object)
case let object as MKPolygon:
    renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: object)
default:
    fatalError("Should have had a renderer")
}
```

Comment: So obvious :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you really know that it's going to be one of those types, just force cast the last one.

```swift
renderer =
  (polygon as? MKMultiPolygon).map(MKMultiPolygonRenderer.init)
  ?? MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: polygon as! MKPolygon)
```

Comment: This is nice but I'd like to avoid the bang.  Thanks :)

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense. That’s what it’s for.